# PineScript - Double Top-Bottom Confirmation Points (Variables)

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading, pine-script-v4

new to PineScript!

I wanted to add entry/close strategy to my script using this indicator (https://www.tradingview.com/script/a0vTLaS6-Double-Top-Bottom-Ultimate-OS/), but I cannot find the **variables** for these points.
[image]

So I would need the variables for Double bottom confirmation point and double top confirmation point, so I can add them to my strategy.entry and strategy.close. Also,The script was more than 300 lines so I figured it'd be better to share the original indicator.

cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `calculate_double_pattern` function (lines 78-117) returns 2 variables - `doubleTop` and `doubleBottom` which are declared in line 244 :`[doubleTop, doubleBottom] = calculate_double_pattern()`

You can visualize the trigger on the chart by using the barcolor:

```
bgcolor(doubleTop ? color.red : na)
bgcolor(doubleBottom ? color.green : na)
```

Note, however, that the original script offset the Double Top/Bottom label to the pivot point after confirmation of the pattern. As can bee seen below, the green backgound indicates the time of actual`doubleBottom` variable trigger and the green label printed N bars earlier below the HL pivot point:

[image]

Comment: It worked! Thanks.